# initialize multidimensional array using lambdas

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, lambda, initialization

I want to initialize an array of doubles containing the first 4 powers of every one of three coefficients of two 3D vectors. I'm trying something like this now:

```
auto getPows = [](double x) { return {1.,x, x*x, x*x*x, x*x*x*x};};
const double allPows[2][3][5] = {
  {getPows(vec1.x()),getPows(vec1.y()),getPows(vec1.z())},
  {getPows(vec2.x()),getPows(vec2.y()),getPows(vec2.z())}
};
```

But it gives a compilation error:

```
error: returning initializer list
```

I've read that lambdas cannot return initializer list implicitly. Changing lambda definition to:

```
auto getPows = [](double x) -> std::initializer_list<double> { return {...};};
```

doesn't help:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::initializer_list<double>’ to ‘const double’ in initialization
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've read that lambdas cannot return initializer list implicitly. Changing lambda definition to [...] doesn't help

The problem is that an `std::initializer_list` is a (lightweight) class, not an initialization list.

I mean... if you use an initialization list to initialize an old C-style array, all goes well

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; // compile
```

but if you use an `std::initializer_list` object, you get a compilation error

```
int b[] = std::initializer_list<int>{ 1, 2, 3 }; // compilation error
```

> What's the right way to do it?

You tagged C++11, you're using `std::intializer_list` and you're using lambda functions...

IMHO you should make the last step using `std::array`s instead of old C-style arrays.

I mean something as

```
#include <array>

int main ()
 {
   auto getPows = [](double x) -> std::array<double, 5u>
                     { return {{ 1., x, x*x, x*x*x, x*x*x*x }}; };

   std::array<std::array<std::array<double, 5u>, 3u>, 2u>
    {{ {{ getPows(1.0), getPows(2.0), getPows(3.0) }},
       {{ getPows(0.1), getPows(0.2), getPows(0.3) }} }};
 }
```

Comment: I would only use `std::array` for generic code which might Need a 0-size array, or if I need to actually copy the array. Otherwise, it's needless complication.

Comment: @Deduplicator - uhmmm... isn't a great complication, IMHO. And a `std::array` has another advantage over a C-style array: can be returned from a function. And can be useful in a case like this.

Comment: As I said, the only advantages are being first-class (meaning copying and assigning work) and the pesky special-casing for 0-size is already done. The disadvantage are having to specify the size, needing the extra-header, fewer guarantees for size (any padding at the end?) and the generally more unwieldy syntax.

Comment: @Deduplicator - sorry: didn't noticed the "copy the array" part.

Answer (score 0):

A [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) is a view, not a container.
As such, never try to use it outside the scope delimiting the lifetime of its referenced sequence.

Next, a `std::initializer_list` is an object, not a *braced-init-list*, which is a syntactic construct. As such, you cannot use it to initialize all the elements of an array, aggregate, or to provide a variable number of arguments to a ctor.
It's just that many containers can be initialized with a sequence from a `std::initializer_list`, and the language has special rules to make them more convenient.

Just provide the elements directly using a *braced-init-list*.